# Query post with content only

Tags: wp-query, loop, editor

I need to loop through the last 3 posts `movie`, but only those which have a content not empty.

I used to do as follow when I used the ACF editor instead of the native one.

> `movie-content` refers to the the slug of my WYSIWYG field.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'post_type' => 'movie',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'movie-content', // ACF editor field name
      'value' => '',
      'compare' => '!='
    )
  )
);
```

Is there any way to do that with the native editor? I'd like to make the conditional test in the request rather than in the loop.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just keep the empty posts as draft? Then in your loop use 'publish' for status?

Comment: Because I have a tons of non empty posts which I still need to display the thumb/title/date and other ACF fields in the archive.

Comment: So you're not using `post_content`, the content is in the ACF field `movie-content` - so you're asking to have a loop where you want the last 3 posts where the meta key `movie-content` is not empty?

Comment: Using ACF was just an example about how I could proceed. I need to display last 3 post types which have a basic content not empty.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question fully, I believe this is what you're after.

As far as I know... There is no WP_Query that you can use to accomplish this.  However, you can use the $wpdb and make a custom query.

```
global $wpdb;

$q = "  SELECT * from {$wpdb->posts} p
        RIGHT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'your_meta_key'
        WHERE  p.post_type = 'your_post_type' AND p.post_status = 'publish' and p.post_content <> ' '
        LIMIT 3";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($q);

foreach ($results as $post){
    // Your Loop goes here
    echo $post->post_content;                
}
```

Just replace the 'your_post_type' etc with your custom fields.

Instead of p.post_content, you could also use pm.meta_value <> ' ' - this will retrieve only posts where the value of the meta field you've chosen is not empty.

in which case, the Query would be:

```
$q = "  SELECT * from {$wpdb->posts } p
        RIGHT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'your_meta_key'
        WHERE  p.post_type = 'your_post_type' AND p.post_status = 'publish' and pm.meta_value <> ' '
        LIMIT 3";
```